# How to connect to rabbitmq cluster with java?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have two instances RabbitMQ provided by IBM:

```
String uri1 = "amqps://admin:password@host1:31281/virtualhost";
String uri2 = "amqps://admin:password@host2:31281/virtualhost";
```

To connect RabbitMQ there are two options:

Option 1:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setUri(uri1);
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
```

Option 2:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setUsername("admin");
factory.setPassword("password");
factory.setHost("host1");
factory.setPort(31281);
factory.setVirtualHost("virtualhost");
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
```

For any reason I can't connect to rabbitmq with this option. This option gets this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:372)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:297)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:900)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:817)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:954)
```

One way to connect to a cluster rabbitmq is:

```
List<AddressType> addressesList = ......;//Read from xml and load
Connection connection = factory.newConnection(addressesList);
```

But I don't know how to connect to a cluster rabbitmq with many URIs, because the option 2 does not works. Please, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, it does not matter connect  rabbitmq with URIs, the problema connect through "List addressesList = ......;" was because this compose instance of rabbit use SSL, without take in account SSL the client java gets this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:120)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:372)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:297)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:900)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:817)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:954)
```

Then we can use a truststore or simply add:

```
factory.useSslProtocol("TLSv1.2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this untested code a try. I am using the [RabbitMQ Java Client javadocs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/current-javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.html) as my reference:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setUsername("admin");
factory.setPassword("password");
factory.setVirtualHost("virtualhost");
Address address1 = new Address("host1", 31281);
Address a2 = new Address("host2", 31281);
List<Address> = new List<Address> { a1, a2 }; // I'm sure this is not the right syntax
AddressResolver addressResolver = factory.createAddressResolver(addresses);
Connection connection = factory.newConnection(addressResolver);
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
```

Comment: I'm was searching how to connecti with many URIs like I said instead a list of addres.

Comment: Hi @luke, I am facing same issue, did you get any solution?

Comment: factory.createAddressResolver(addresses); this line didn't work.